# How to split by nonescaped dot and by ignoring double blackslash?

Tags: java, regex

I need to split data by dot. And I have escaped dot(.), that I should ignore. Also I should ignore escaped backslash too (\).
For example,

```
data1\\.d\\\\\.ata2\\\\.da\.ta3.data4
```

This string should be splitted to for substrings like as

```
data1\\
d\\\\\.ata2\\\\
da\.ta3
data4
```

I cannot to create regex for that. Do you know, it is possible?
I tried to use following:

```
(?<!\\((\\\\){2,}))\\. - not working
```

I can create following regex if escaped slash defined only one time:

```
"((?<!\\\\)\\.)|((?=([^\\\\]*((\\\\\\\\)+[^\\\\]*)))\\.)";
```

For example `data1\\.d\.ata2.da\.ta3.data4` splitted correctly:

```
data1\\
d\.ata2
da\.ta3
data4
```

But I cannot detect backslash definition even number times.
Can you help me, please?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may extract these strings using

```java
(?s)(?:[^\\.]|\\.)+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/AhR6Vg/2). Details:

- `(?s)` - enable the `Pattern.DOTALL` flag so that `.` could match across lines
- `(?:[^\\.]|\\.)+` - one or more occurrences of any char other than `\` and `.`, or a `\` followed with any char.

See a [Java demo](https://ideone.com/osscnp):

```java
String line = "data1\\\\.d\\.ata2.da\\.ta3.data4";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?s)(?:[^\\\\.]|\\\\.)+");
Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
List<String> res = new ArrayList<>();
while(m.find()) {
    res.add(m.group());
}
System.out.println(res);
// => [data1\\, d\.ata2, da\.ta3, data4]
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use this regex to get your matches:

```
(?=[^.])[^.\\]*(?:\\.[^.\\]*)*(?=\.|$)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/6FosPf/4)

**RegEx Demo:**

- `(?=[^.])`: Make sure there is non-dot character ahead
- `[^.\\]*`: Match 0+ of any character that is not a `.` not a `\`
- `(?:\\.[^.\\]*)*`: A non-capture group that matches an backslash followed by an escaped character and that should be followed by 0 or more of any character that is not a `.` not a `\`. Match 0 or more of this group
- `(?=\.|$)`: Make sure we have a dot or end of line ahead

Comment: @ЭльфияВалиева This won't work if the escape sequence is the first in the match, then it will get skipped. See [how it fails](https://regex101.com/r/6FosPf/3).

Comment: That can be easily fixed as you can see in edited answer. And it will still be faster than your regex